# jquery autocomplete with dwr

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, dwr

has anyone tried using jquery autocomplete plugin with DWR as data source.

i need autocompletion functionality for my page, but i am also using dwr instead of typical ajax call.

i found one link regarding this, but i am unable to locate the source code for this!

http://www.nabble.com/-autocomplete--jquery-%2B-dwr-td22691104s27240.html

can somebody please help me locating this source and using it?

regards

Comment: at least could somebody point me to the jquery ui version of autocomplete plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Arun is right with his approach, but it could be needed to change a little thing. I tested it with DWR-3.0.0-RC2, jquery-1.7.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js. 
Instead of:

```
$('#autoCompTxt').autocomplete(data) ;
```

define the *source* parameter:

```
$('#autoCompTxt').autocomplete({source:data});
```

Moreover that good answer can be slightly improved checking the *autoCompTxt* length. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#autoCompTxt').keyup(function() {
        var val = $('#autoCompTxt').val();
        if(val.length>2) {  // check length
            TestService.ajaxAutoCompleteTest(val, function(data) {
                // handle successful DWR response
                $('#autoCompTxt').autocomplete({source:data});
            });
        } else {
            $('#autoCompTxt').autocomplete({source:[]});  // clean
        }
    });
});
```

Of course, script and css imports and input text should be kept (see Arun's answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple to use the jQuery UI autocomplete plugin (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) with dwr.

**Example**:

```
jQuery( function() {  
    Cities.getAllCities(function(data) {
         var input = jQuery("#cities");
         input.autocomplete({
             minLength: 1,
             source: data
         });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what Øyvind Marthinsen wrote, but I think that something like this:

```
jQuery(inputSelector).autocomplete({

.....................

    source : function(request, response) {
        TheClass.theMethod(request.term,{
            callback: function(TheDataFromServer) {
                var arrayOfData = [];
                for(i = 0;i < TheDataFromServer.length;i++){
                    arrayOfData.push(TheDataFromServer[i].someStringIfDataNotString);
                }
                response(arrayOfData);
            }
        });
    }

.....................

});
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple, use DWR's ajax calling-technique and use jQuery's autocomplete method inside the callback option. Please refer the below example. Script imports, CSS imports should be in this order

```
<LINK href='<%=contextPath %>/styles/jquery.autocomplete.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<LINK href='<%=contextPath %>/styles/main.css' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript"src="<%=contextPath%>/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="<%=contextPath%>/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>`enter code here`
<script type='text/javascript' src='<%=contextPath %>/scripts/jquery-latest.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<%=contextPath %>/scripts/jquery.bgiframe.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<%=contextPath %>/dwr/interface/TestService.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<%=contextPath %>/scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>

TEXT BOX SHOULD BE LIKE BELOW

<input id="autoCompTxt" type="text">

JQUERY FUNCTION SHOULD BE WRITTEN THIS WAY

$(function() {
    $('#autoCompTxt').keyup(function() { 
        var val = $('#autoCompTxt').val() ;
        TestService.ajaxAutoCompleteTest(val, function(data){
           $('#autoCompTxt').autocomplete(data) ;
        });
    });

});
```