# How to achieve auto completion

Tags: java, user-interface, autocomplete

I am planning to develop a small search engine with auto complete feature based on the key entered contained in database (somewhat like google). Is there a recommend approach to performing the auto-completion. I'm doing it in java.

Comment: I don't think it's a well-phrased question but I don't think it warrants closing

Comment: @BrianAgnew I voted to close because it's highly subjective. There is no right answer with this type of "How do I...?" question. Maybe a better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: autocompletion based on what? basicly you should just have a class `Dictionary` with an `ArrayList<String>` in it and do some algorythm on it

Comment: It's funny how there are already two answers when you haven't even told us the UI framework you want to use. Some frameworks already provide everything you need for auto-completion, for others you might have to do it yourself.

Comment: @Arian i am open to suggestions regarding the UI framework.

Comment: So your actual question is "Which UI framework should I use?". If your app will run in the browser, then jquery; if it's a desktop application, then javafx2 or swing; if it's an eclipse plug-in, jface. Just build your UI basics, and when that works, ask again about auto-completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subscribe to various events (as required) similar to `TextChanged`

See these questions:

[Java equivalent to C# TextBox TextChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721197/java-equivalent-to-c-sharp-textbox-textchanged-event)

[Auto complete textbox in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861921/auto-complete-textbox-in-java-swing)

[swing autocomplete text field / drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268091/swing-autocomplete-text-field-drop-down)

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me how this app is deployed etc., and I've read it (correctly or incorrectly) as a requirement for a bash-like autocomplete feature.

[JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) is a command-line library for Java. It provides cursor-key navigation, history and completion. Unfortunately the doc isn't great, but start with the [Completor](http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) interface.

If you're after a web interface, I would take a look at [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) (which exposes Java objects as Javascript objects) and implement auto-complete as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519165/jquery-autocomplete-with-dwr).

Answer (score 0):

Its not that difficult. You can use java along with [jquery auto complete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Here you just need to make a call like :

```
 $("#id").autocomplete("MyJSP.jsp");
```

So your background processing is done by your java and this loads the features with the auto complete  plugin. Easy enough ! You can take a look at this [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery/) .

They have a nice Spring way of doing things too .